# Convert Text to Number Excel in LotusScript

Tags: excel, lotus-notes, export-to-excel, lotusscript, vba

Can anyone guide me on how do i convert a Text To Number?
I've been trying to use 
xlapp.selection.FormatNumber = "#,##0.00" But won't work because the exported column turns out to be in a text format. thanks for your help, really appreciate it.

-Edit
I am using lotusscript to export a view into excel. My dilemma is that the exported column containing Numbers turns out to be exported as Text and Needs to be converted to number first before i can use xlapp.selection.FormatNumber = "#,##0.00" to format it. I would like to know the syntax to convert the column into number by means of using lotusscript.

Comment: Note that if any of these answers fits you, please accept it by clicking on the tick on the left of the answer (this is not too late to do it) - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234 for more information  
Or else, you can answer you own question (it is even [highly recommended](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)) and accept it. This way, you can share your knowledge with the community and kind of *close* the question.

Answer (score 3):

What about [`CDec`](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/convert-to-decimal.htm) ?

Comment: i get the idea but i i'm having trouble coding them. Would you show me an example on how the syntax looks like?, TIA

Comment: you can have a look at the link i gave in my answer or also [there](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/quicktips/qt/cvtchrexcel.htm)

Comment: xlApp.Range("C:C").Select 
FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*1" this what i only have, but doesn't seem to work thou :(

Comment: this is **formula**, not **vba**. Try this: `xlApp.Range("C:C").Select FormulaR1C1 = "=VALUE(RC[-3]*1)"`. Please edit your question to explain better what you want, or else, nobody can help you!

Answer (score 1):

To convert a column value into a number in LotusScript, use the [CDbl](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_CDBL_FUNCTION.html) function.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i figured it out. My Array was in a String Data Type /Facepalm